# Scrolledtext получить все записанные значения

Tags: python, tkinter

После того как записаны все значения в Scrolledtext, мне надо их все записать в файл. Как я могу это сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, получить текст можно с данным методом:

```
scrolledtext.get(1.0, END)
```